# PHP inherit class and use functions defined in external files

Tags: php, function, inheritance

This looks simple but I have been struggling this to get working. Please refer following two files, I am trying to use common.php file's public functions and inheriting DBConnection class in login.php, but it doesn't seem to be working, getting error code '500' (internal server error). If I put all common.php stuffs inside login.php it just works fine but I want to use DBConnection class and public functions in many classes so getting around to make this working. Can someone help?

common.php

```
<?php

function getStatusCodeMessage($status) {
    $codes = Array(
        100 => 'Continue',
        101 => 'Switching Protocols',
        200 => 'OK',
        201 => 'Created',
        202 => 'Accepted',
        203 => 'Non-Authoritative Information',
        204 => 'No Content',
        205 => 'Reset Content',
        206 => 'Partial Content',
        300 => 'Multiple Choices',
        301 => 'Moved Permanently',
        302 => 'Found',
        303 => 'See Other',
        304 => 'Not Modified',
        305 => 'Use Proxy',
        306 => '(Unused)',
        307 => 'Temporary Redirect',
        400 => 'Bad Request',
        401 => 'Unauthorized',
        402 => 'Payment Required',
        403 => 'Forbidden',
        404 => 'Not Found',
        405 => 'Method Not Allowed',
        406 => 'Not Acceptable',
        407 => 'Proxy Authentication Required',
        408 => 'Request Timeout',
        409 => 'Conflict',
        410 => 'Gone',
        411 => 'Length Required',
        412 => 'Precondition Failed',
        413 => 'Request Entity Too Large',
        414 => 'Request-URI Too Long',
        415 => 'Unsupported Media Type',
        416 => 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable',
        417 => 'Expectation Failed',
        500 => 'Internal Server Error',
        501 => 'Not Implemented',
        502 => 'Bad Gateway',
        503 => 'Service Unavailable',
        504 => 'Gateway Timeout',
        505 => 'HTTP Version Not Supported'
    );

    return (isset($codes[$status])) ? $codes[$status] : '';
}

// Helper method to send a HTTP response code/message
function sendResponse($status = 200, $body = '', $content_type = 'text/html') {
    $status_header = 'HTTP/1.1 ' . $status . ' ' . getStatusCodeMessage($status);
    header($status_header);
    header('Content-type: ' . $content_type);
    echo $body;
}

class DBConnection 
{
    protected $db;

    // Constructor - open DB connection
    function __construct() 
    {
        $this->db = new mysqli('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');
        $this->db->autocommit(FALSE);
    }

    // Destructor - close DB connection
    function __destruct() 
    {
        $this->db->close();
    }
}

?>
```

login.php

```
   <?php

include 'common.php';

class UserAPI extends DBConnection {
    function login() {
        // Check for required parameters
        if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {

            // Put parameters into local variables
            $username = $_POST["username"];
            $password = $_POST["password"];

            // Look up code in database
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT user_username, user_password FROM User WHERE user_username=?');
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($existingUsername, $existingPassword);
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                break;
            }
            $stmt->close();

            // Bail if Email exist
            if ($existingUsername && $password == $existingPassword) {
                $result = array(
                    "success" => 1,
                );

                sendResponse(200, json_encode($result));
                return true;
            }

            sendResponse(400, 'Invalid Username or Password. Please try again.');
            return false;
        }

        sendResponse(400, 'Invalid request');
        return false;
    }
}

$api = new UserAPI;
$api-> login();

?>
```

[EDIT]

I made login.php simplest. It gives me error when I have "extends DBConnection", if I remove it works!

```
<?php

include 'common.php';

class UserAPI extends DBConnection {
    function login() {
        echo "OK";
        return true;
    }
}

$api = new UserAPI;
$api-> login();

?>
```

Comment: Probably a silly question, but are both files in the same directory? You will probably need to check your server log for the actual error message. That would give us/you more of a hint as to where to look for whats causing the error.

Comment: Yes, file is getting including correctly. I have checked if ((include 'vars.php') == 'OK') {
    echo 'OK';
} which works fine. I get error only when I try to access public function or extends the class.

Comment: Wait, a global method can't have access modifier like public, private or protected. Remove those modifiers from the functions in common.php

Comment: Have you remove all white-space and newlines before trying to set headers? Like I mentioned previously, you're going to have to enable error logging, and check out your server/http error log file.

Comment: Hi Phil, please see my EDIT, I have removed everything and still the same error only when I add "extends DBConnection", without it, i get code 200 which is success. I will have to research on how to see this error file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot declare functions "public" if they are NOT part of a class. This will trigger a fatal PHP syntax error.

Solutions: Either wrap those functions inside a class, and make them static.

Or remove the visibility modifier "public".

Comment: I just tested it on wampserver, and got a parse-error rather than fatal error.

Comment: I'd consider any errors that kill the script "fatal", whatever the correct wording is in this case. :)

Comment: Hi Sven, I have removed it and tried again but the same error code 500! Please bear with me, this is first PHP pages I am trying to write.

Comment: Then google how to display PHP errors or how to grab them from the server log file. Without a proper error message this will not lead to a solution.

Comment: Hi Sven, see my EDIT, I have removed everything and still the same error only when I add "extends DBConnection", without it, i get code 200 which is success.

Comment: I don't see any obvious errors, so all we need is the error message that is hidden behind the status 500. After that I guess solving it will be very easy.

Answer (score 0):

I copy your code to my local and run it, it works.

Maybe your DB has issue.

How about you comment out `$this->db = new mysqli('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');` related codes.

Comment: Hi Zac, database working fine absolutely. I think all i need is the error log. I don;t know how to get error logs but will figure it out.